# Plotting a Derivative in Scheme

Tags: plot, scheme, racket, derivative

I wrote a derivative function as follows:

```
(define (der f h)
 (lambda (x)
 (/ (- (f(+ x h)) (f x)) h)))
```

and another function for finding second and third derivatives :

```
(define (der-multiple f h n)
 (if (= 0 n)
  0
  (der (f h)))
       (- n 1))
```

I tried to plot the derivative of sin(x) as follows, but it did not work.

```
(define (f x) (der (sin x) 0.5))
(require plot)
(plot (function f (- 5) 5 #:label "sine^-1(x)")
  #:x-min -5 #:x-max 5 #:y-min -5 #:y-max 5)
```

lang racket is imported, but all I am getting is a white screen. Did I do something wrong here? Should I change (lambda (x)) within the derivative function to something else to make the function easier to plot?

**Updated Code**

```
(define (der f h)
  (lambda (x)
  (/ (- (f(+ x h)) (f x))
     h)))

(define (der-multiple f h n)
  (if (= 0 n)
      f
      (der-multiple (der f h) h (- n 1))))
(define (der-sin-fourth h)
(der-multiple sin h 4))
(plot (function (der-sin-fourth 0.5) (- 5) 5 #:label "sine^-4(x)")
        :x-min -5 #:x-max 5 #:y-min -5 #:y-max 5)
```

Comment: I'll recommend using two-sided estimation: (/ (- (f (+ x h) (f (- x h))) 2.0) rather than the one-sided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `der` returns a function of `x`, which is fine.  But your

```
(define (f x) (der (sin x) 0.5))
```

has a number of problems.  First, since `der` returns a function, all that `f` does is return a function - it does no computation on `x`.  Probably you wanted:

```
(define f (der (sin x) 0.5))
```

so that `f` is actually bound to a function of `x`.

Second, the argument to `der` is expected to be a function, but with `(sin x)` you, at best, pass in a number.

In summary, probably you want something like:

```
(define f (der sin 0.5))
```

Note, your `h` of 0.5 is probably too big to get a reasonable derivative (recall `sin` is periodic outside of {0, 2pi}).  You'll have no issues making `h` very small.  Of course, when you plot it you can step `x` by 0.5 if you want.

Your `der-multiple` function isn't correct in a number of ways.  Here is the proper version:

```
(define (der-n f h n)
  (if (zero? n)
      f
      (der-n (der f h) h (- n 1))))
```

Comment: I created a sin function using a function named power series. I corrected my code to match what you suggested, but my function still doesn't plot a graph as I intended. Should the plot of the "f" you defined here work or am I missing something?

Comment: Before plotting anything did you confirm that your `sin` and `der of sin` functions are working?  That is, is the problem with plotting or with computing?

Comment: No, this seems to be the problem. Why is it incorrect to write **(der (sin x)0.5)** if the sin function is defined in scheme?

Comment: Because `(sin x)` will attempt to run the `sin` function using the value of `x` and then return the result which is a number between -1 and 1.  For your `der` function, the first argument is supposed to be a function, not a number between -1 and 1.

Comment: When I make h very small as you recommended my graph oscillates instead of doing what I expected. Can you take a look at the code I edited and tell me if you could think of a good reason why this happens?

Comment: [Thanks for the check mark.]  Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6630605 of the code with the result for the first derivative of `sin`.  Because the first derivative of `sin` is `cos` I also display the `cos` value for comparison.  The derivative function is pretty close.